# Problems with when trying to sum time using function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, leaflet

I have tried several suggestions on how to sum hours and minutes but all have failed to me.
I'm using this script as a start https://olanaso.github.io/Leaflet-Select-Polygons/# and need to have more rows with other totals from selected polygons, one of them is time (h:mm 00:00). Every polygon has properties with hour and minute, some has 00:00. I have manage to add more totals but when it comes to sum the time it has not worked for me. When you select polygons the totals adds up and when deselect a polygon the totals updates with removing that value. This function "timestrToSec" is one I have been trying, but getting the error "time.split is not a function". Also I don't need days just hours and minutes summed together like "300:15 h:mm" (3 hundred hours and 15 minutes) when selecting polygons och deselecting.

```
$.each(statesData.features, function(index, feature) {
var name = `${feature.properties.ZIPCODE} ${feature.properties.Name}  ( ${feature.properties.average_time} -  ${feature.properties.CITY})`
placenames.push(name);
zipcodes[name] = feature.properties.ZIPCODE;
time = feature.properties.average_time
});

More....   
// Now get the totals of selected polygons
var detailshow = function() {
var result = ''
var total = 0
var total1 = 0
var total2 = 0
for (var i = 0; i < featuresSelected.length; i++) {

var properties = featuresSelected[i].feature.properties
    result +=
        `
    ${properties.CITY}<br>
    Zipcode: ${properties.ZIPCODE}
    <a href="#" onclick=dellayer(${properties.ZIPCODE})>Delete</a>
    <hr>`;
    total += properties.amount,
    total1 += properties.average_time,
    total2 += properties.distance

    var convertTime = function (input, separator) {
    var pad = function(input) {return input < 10 ? "0" + input : input;};
        return [
        pad(Math.floor(input / 3600)),
        pad(Math.floor(input % 3600 / 60)),
        pad(Math.floor(input % 60)),
        ].join(typeof separator !== 'undefined' ?  separator : ':' );
    }

var resultTime = convertTime(total1);

}
return {
    result: result,
    total: total,
    resultTime: resultTime,
    total2: total2
};
}

detailsselected.update = function(arrayselected) {

var details = detailshow()
this._div.innerHTML =
'<b>Zipcodes</b><br>' + 
'Total time: <b>' + details.resultTime + ' hh:mm:ss</b><br>' +
'Amount: <b>' + details.total + ' st</b><br>' +
'Distance: <b>' + details.total2.toFixed(1) + ' km</b><br>';
$('#suma', window.parent.document).val(details.total, details.resultTime, details.total2);


};

detailsselected.addTo(map);
```

This is part of the json file structure:

```
var statesData = new L.LayerGroup;
var statesData = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"ZIPCODE":12345,"CITY":"LONDON","REGION":"REGION SOUTH","amount":1088,"average_time":"06:39","distance":2.2},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":...
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really try to follow everything you're doing, but if all you're trying to do is to add together `hh:mm` times, then something like this should work:

```js
const addTimes = (hhmm1, hhmm2) => {
  const [h1, m1] = hhmm1.split(':').map(Number)
  const [h2, m2] = hhmm2.split(':').map(Number)
  const minutes = 60 * h1 + m1 + 60 * h2 + m2
  return `${Math.floor(minutes / 60)}:${String(minutes % 60).padStart(2, '0')}`
}

const addManyTimes = (ts) => ts.reduce(addTimes, '0:00') 

console .log (addTimes ('3:41', '7:55')) //=> '11:36'

console .log (addManyTimes (['2:12', '3:07', '8:39', '6:21', '5:59'])) //=> '26:18'
```

It would be easy enough to extend this to seconds as well if that were necessary.

Comment: Hmmm I did change to your suggestion I think... but still the same error.. change to this `const addTimes = (time) => {
  const [h1, m1] = time.split(':').map(Number)
  //const [h2, m2] = hhmm2.split(':').map(Number)
  const minutes = 60 * h1 + m1` as my properties.time I guess should be there instead of "hhmm1" and try to output it like so `Total time: <b>' + addTimes(details.total1) + ' hh:mm</b><br>'` Error is time.split is not a function... same as my previous try

Comment: My function assumes that times are in `"hh:mm"` format.  If you have some missing times or ones not listed as `"0:00"` or `"00:00"` or some such, then you will have to replace them with one of those formats before calling this function.  More generally, it's really not clear to me what it is you're looking for.  Can you restate your question more concisely?  I answered as if the question was, "How do you add the values of two numbers in an `"hh:mm"` format?"  If you are looking for something else, please try to rephrase your question.

Comment: Never stated it was between two numbers, as I mentioned the function is selecting polygons (by dblclick) and the result has to add the time for each polygon selected so it can probably be up to 20-50 polygons selected at one time. Sorry for not being clear, but I guess you have to look into the link to understand more what I want...

Comment: Note that the questions here should stand alone.  External links are fine for additional context, but the question should contain enough to allow people to see and reproduce the issue you're having.  I *still* don't really know what your inputs are, or what output you're expecting from it (and I did look at that link.)  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks Scott for taking the time, I did a new approach went with summarize seconds instead, and from seconds to h:mm:ss seemed to work much better for me. The problem I had is solved...

Comment: For future users who run across this question, could you updated to explain how you solved it?

Comment: Done, did change the code above. I went to change the input data converting hh:mm:ss to plain seconds, summing the second and then convert back to time format seemed to be an easier way, for me at least...